# python - make pool of workers write rows to a global Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a pool of workers with `pool.apply_async` which are working on a function called `process_data` which returns a `numpy` 1D array. I would like to combine these 1D arrays into a matrix. This is the current code:

```
def process_data(x, y, z)
    # stuff happens 
    return 1Darray   


pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

jobs = []

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(100):
    job = pool.apply_async(process_data, (x, y, z,))
    jobs.append(job)
```

How should I get each returned result and add it to a global matrix where each `1Darray` is a row in the matrix?

Do I need Locks and/or queues?

I know that `np.column_stack()` stacks arrays in a matrix I am not sure how to achieve this from the `multiprocessing` side.

Comment: Yes, you must use some synchronization method to serialize write access to the common data.  There are many ways to do this.  Why not just wait until all process complete, collect their results into a list, and use `column_stack`, just as you suggested?

Comment: @Prune That is the idea I had in my mind. How do I collect the results from all processes though? ( also assume I have much more than a 100 processes if that makes any difference). I am fairly new to multiprocessing. If this works I could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use the `.get` method on the job object returned by `apply_async`. This will give you a list containing (in this case 100) 1D arrays.

You can then apply `np.array` and to produce a 2D numpy array of shape (length_of_list, lenght_of_arrays).

```
def process_data(x, y, z):
    # stuff happens 
    return 1Darray   


pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

jobs = []

for i in range(100):
    job = pool.apply_async(process_data, (x, y, z,))
    jobs.append(job.get())

matrix = np.array(jobs)
```